# came up the path

Tags: meaning

She was still crying when she suddenly noticed Gabriel Oak, ***who had come up the path on his way to the church***,and was watching her sympathetically.
What is the meaning of the sentence above?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't "come up that path"?

Comment: yes my mistake ,it is ''come up that path''

Comment: Please provide source for the quote. Also try to explain why this sentence or phrase is hard to understand

Comment: @JamesK Gabriel Oak is a character in _Far from the Madding Crowd_.

Comment: @KateBunting I know. I was asking to remind the OP to include the information.

Answer (score 2):

"come up the path" basically means that, from the perspective of the speaker, someone has approached from the far end of a path towards the near end of the path. With a church, there is often a path that leads to the entrance.